# MediaCodec Decoder issues with dequeueOutputBuffer call (H.264)

Tags: encoding, h.264, android-mediacodec

**The Question:**
Why do I su...I mean, what is going on with my decoder? It's always returning timed out (-1) when I try to get it's juicy output data!

Let me start by saying I've read through the relative threads, but still can't solve the problem. I really needs some guidance and assistance here. Okay, so what I am doing is passing AVC encoded data to my decoder. The encoder  works, pulling data from camera preview, where I do the conversion from NV21 to NV12 before passing to the encoder.

The first data available from the encoder has the `codec-specific-data`, which I pass to the `ConfigureDecoder(ByteBuffer csd0, ByteBuffer csd1)` function to create and configure the decoder, which does not throw any errors.

```
public void ConfigureDecoder(ByteBuffer csd0, ByteBuffer csd1)
{
    try
    {
        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Decoder codec creation failed: " + e.toString());
    }

    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, 320, 240);
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd0);
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", csd1);
    decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

    try
    {
        decoder.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "Decoder configured");
    }
    catch(CodecException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Decoder config start failed: " + e.getDiagnosticInfo());
    }
}
```

---

The following function is called once the encoder notifies that there is encoded data available (after the codec-specific data). First, I get an available decoder input buffer, if successful I fill it with the encoded data (verified) and add it to decoder queue. Then everything goes to hell, I try to retrieve data from the decoder using `dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);` which always returns -1.

---

```
public void offerDecoder(byte[] input, int offset, int size, long presentationTimeUs, int flags)
{   
    int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
    Log.d(TAG, "Decoder dequeueInputBuffer = " + inputBufIndex);

    if(inputBufIndex >= 0)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get valid buffer and push into the decoder input buffer
            ByteBuffer inputBuf = decoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
            inputBuf.clear();
            inputBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, size, presentationTimeUs, flags);
        }
        catch(MediaCodec.CodecException ce)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Decoder adding data error: " + ce.getDiagnosticInfo());
        }
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    Log.d(TAG, "Decoder dequeueOutputBuffer = " + outIndex);

    switch(outIndex)
    {
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
            ByteBuffer outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "Decoder dequeueOutputBuffer = INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
            break;

        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
            //MediaFormat bufferFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat(outIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "Decoder dequeueOutputBuffer = INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED");
            break;

        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
            //Total fail, something is really wrong if you are always receiving -1 from dequeueOutputBuffer
            //Log.d(TAG, "Decoder dequeueOutputBuffer = INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER");
            break;

        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Decoder out buffer info-->" + bufferInfo.offset + "--" + bufferInfo.size + "--" + bufferInfo.flags + "--" + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            ByteBuffer buffer = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outIndex); 
            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
            break;
    }
}
```

If your reached this point in the post I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the issue here is that the API gives you the illusion that decoding would be synchronous - it isn't.

When you give the decoder one input packet, it will start decoding it - now you only check it once immediately afterwards, when the decoder returns -1 indicating that it doesn't have any more output (yet).

You could increase the timeoutUs parameter to have it wait a little longer to see if the decoder returns something, or set it to -1 to wait indefinitely.

But if you always wait for the output immediately for each input packet, you'll get pretty bad performance (and in case of broken input, you might not get any output at all); you should give the decoder as much data you've got to decode so far (until dequeueInputBuffer indicates that no input buffers are available at the moment), and use any output buffers that the decoder provides. If targeting only Android 5.0 and higher is an option for you, you should look into the callback API (`MediaCodec.setCallback`), which is much clearer with this, not having to poll for the output.

Comment: IIRC, the AVC codecs want to be fed about four access units before they'll start doing anything. I expect this varies between devices. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, the solution is just remove the following line from your code,

```
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd0);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", csd1);
```